# xpath 2.0 query - how to test if the current element is the first element with this name in a xml document

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following xsl template:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paragraph.para">
        <!-- if first para in document -->
        <!--<xsl:if test="//para[1] intersect .">-->
        <xsl:if test="//para[1] intersect .">
            <xsl:attribute name="space-after">10pt</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="background-color">yellow</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]">
                <xsl:attribute name="text-indent">0em</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="parent::item">
                <xsl:attribute name="text-indent">0em</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="text-indent">1em</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem I am having is verifying that the current node of the template is the very first para node in the document from the following xml:

```
<document>
    <section>
        <paragraph>
            <para>Para Text 1*#</para>
            <para>Para Text 2</para>
        </paragraph>
    </section>
    <paragraph>
        <para>Para Text 3*</para>
        <para>Para Text 4</para>
        <para>Para Text 5</para>
        <sub-paragraph>
            <para>Para Text 6*</para>
            <para>Para Text 7</para>
        </sub-paragraph>
    </paragraph>
    <appendix>
        <paragraph>
            <para>Para Text 8*</para>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph>
            <para>Para Text 9</para>
        </paragraph>        
    </appendix>
</document>
```

the xpath I am currently using is "//para[1] intersect ." which is selecting the first para for each group of para (denoted with a * in XML sample). Any ideas on how I can just select the first occurance of para within document (denoted with a #)?

Comment: @Mike, Good question (+1)! See my answer for recommended expressions in both XPath 2.0 and XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0) one can use**:

```
count( (//para)[1] | .) = 1
```

This works also in XPath 2.0, but may not be as efficient as using the `intersect` operator.

**I would recommend the following XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
(//para)[1] is .
```

Do note the use of **[the XPath 2.0 `is` operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-NodeComp)**.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, useful to know the xpath 1.0 version as well. Cheers Mike

Comment: I tried to use this in the context of checking the current node, but it didn't work as I expected. I wanted to iterate over a previous query's result, and test that the specific item I was iterating over in the DOMNodeList matched a selector. I wrote `$xpath->query($currentNodeSelector . 'is .', $currentNode);`, I guess it is wrong, but what is the right way?

Comment: @ScottAnderson, My first guess is that your host of XPath (probably a browser or Javascript) only supports XPath 1.0 and not XPath 2.0. If you ask a new question and send me a comment with the link to it, I will have a look

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out the solution myself, a slight change is needed in the xpath adding brackets around the //para limits the selection:

"(//para)[1] intersect ." you can also use "(//para)[1] is ." to get the same result, and on this occassion I belive the "is" version is more readable.